# How to elegantly add an online JavaScript dependency to your source code?

Tags: javascript, ajax, sockets, http

Suppose that I want to publish a JavaScript library. There is one problem, though: certain features of this library depend on another library, which is located in a permanent url. Instead of expecting my users to include the dependency, I want to automate this. My question is: what is the most elegant/short way to load such dependency from bare JavaScript?

In other words, I need a short, cross-browser implementation of the "load" function bellow:

```
MyLib = (function(){
    var locals = blabla;
    load("http://foo.com/lib.js", function(){
         // Library loaded! I can use it here.
         ...
    });
    return {...};
})();
```

**Note this can not depend on any other external library (such as `requirejs`) since such dependency would beat the purpose by definition. After all, it would just force my user to add that dependency instead anyway!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want cross-browser

```
function load(url, callback) {
    var head    = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script  = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src  = url;

    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;

    head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Requirejs for that case:

```
require(["http://foo.com/lib.js"], function (lib) {
});
```

More info: http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html , https://egghead.io/lessons/requirejs-introduction-to-requirejs

Comment: Thanks! Yet, the problem with this solution is now my user has to manually add "requirejs", which beats the purpose. I could inline "requirejs" inside my library, but that would increase the size considerably. The solution I'm asking for is a short, self-contained function that does the asynchronous loading.